# How do you animate a button while allowing user interaction? (Xcode 8, iOS 10)

Tags: ios, animation, uibutton

I would like to animate a button to move across a screen, allowing you to click it where ever it is at that point in time. Not where it ends up.

I am currently using a work-around by overriding the `touchesBegan` in order to achieve this. However, I can't get it to work with newly created buttons outside of `viewDidLoad`. I've been told `.allowUserInteraction` is all that is necessary in Xcode 8 and iOS 10. That is, I do not need to override `touchesBegan`.

But I've been unable to achieve this. Can someone provide simple code as an example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add an animation option to the animation. add `UIViewAnimationOption.allowUserInteraction` as a parameter to the [animation method](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622451-animate), depending on which method you are using

[option reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewanimationoptions/1622440-allowuserinteraction)

Maybe provide us your code on how you are doing your animation, so we can more accurately determine what you should do

Answer (score 0):

Add animations:---

Before animation:

self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

and in animation completion block:

self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

Comment: Or you can do vice versa